# php SoapClient override __dorequest does not change xml after str_replace

Tags: php, soap

I override the php SoapClient class in order to add an attribute to the  element. When I print the changed code, just before sending, the XML seems to be changed as supposed but when reviewing the XML by __getLastRequest() the XML seems not to have changed at all. In the code I try to add a attribute to the  element. Maybe someone knows why the $request_new XML string not send to the server? (OutputXML() is just some nice formating with colering to html)

```
class SoapClientDebug extends SoapClient
{
    public function __doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way = 0) {
        // change / add whatever needed
        $request_new = str_replace( '<env:Body', '<env:Body ns1:Id="TheBody"', $request );
        // debug out
        OutputXML($request_new);
        // calling parent
        return parent::__doRequest($request_new, $location, $action, $version, $one_way);
    }
}
```

inspected XML outputted before calling parent __doRequest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ns1="http://logius.nl/digipoort/koppelvlakservices/1.2/" xmlns:ns2="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:ns3="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/security/2000-12">
 <env:Header>
  <ns3:Security env:mustUnderstand="true">
   <ns2:Signature>
    <ns2:SignedInfo>
     <ns2:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
    <ns2:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
   <ns2:Reference>
    <ns2:Transforms>
     <ns2:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
    </ns2:Transforms>
   <ns2:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
  <ns2:DigestValue>$6hpmccmjxQmAI143OhQfIWpkryw=</ns2:DigestValue>
   </ns2:Reference>
  </ns2:SignedInfo>
 <ns2:SignatureValue>sv8n4h0rV4Xmbl+M+w+MLl7lVA8KFsoWRx5DqSKkwSie32jOFoJt0WvH6UWRQI</ns2:SignatureValue>
  <ns2:KeyInfo>
   <ns2:X509Data>
    <ns2:X509IssuerName>CN=TestSignCert</ns2:X509IssuerName>
     <ns2:X509SerialNumber>75496503122422458150193540449068096025</ns2:X509SerialNumber>
      </ns2:X509Data>
     </ns2:KeyInfo>
    </ns2:Signature>
   </ns3:Security>
  </env:Header>
 <env:Body ns1:Id="TheBody">
  <ns1:aanleverRequest>
   <ns1:berichtsoort>Omzetbelasting</ns1:berichtsoort>
    <ns1:aanleverkenmerk>Happyflow</ns1:aanleverkenmerk>
     <ns1:identiteitBelanghebbende>
      <ns1:nummer/>
     <ns1:type/>
    </ns1:identiteitBelanghebbende>
   <ns1:rolBelanghebbende>Intermediair</ns1:rolBelanghebbende>
    <ns1:berichtInhoud>
     <ns1:mimeType/>
    <ns1:bestandsnaam/>
   <ns1:inhoud/>
  </ns1:berichtInhoud>
 <ns1:autorisatieAdres>https://secure.inepd.nl/inloon</ns1:autorisatieAdres>
  </ns1:aanleverRequest>
 </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

Reviewing XML by __getLastRequest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ns1="http://logius.nl/digipoort/koppelvlakservices/1.2/" xmlns:ns2="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:ns3="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/security/2000-12">
 <env:Header>
  <ns3:Security env:mustUnderstand="true">
   <ns2:Signature>
    <ns2:SignedInfo>
     <ns2:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
    <ns2:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
   <ns2:Reference>
    <ns2:Transforms>
     <ns2:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
    </ns2:Transforms>
   <ns2:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
  <ns2:DigestValue>$6hpmccmjxQmAI143OhQfIWpkryw=</ns2:DigestValue>
   </ns2:Reference>
  </ns2:SignedInfo>
 <ns2:SignatureValue>sv8n4h0rV4Xmbl+M+w+MLl7lVA8KFsoWRx5DqSKkwSie32jOFoJt0WvH6UWRQI</ns2:SignatureValue>
  <ns2:KeyInfo>
   <ns2:X509Data>
    <ns2:X509IssuerName>CN=TestSignCert</ns2:X509IssuerName>
     <ns2:X509SerialNumber>75496503122422458150193540449068096025</ns2:X509SerialNumber>
      </ns2:X509Data>
     </ns2:KeyInfo>
    </ns2:Signature>
   </ns3:Security>
  </env:Header>
 <env:Body>
  <ns1:aanleverRequest>
   <ns1:berichtsoort>Omzetbelasting</ns1:berichtsoort>
    <ns1:aanleverkenmerk>Happyflow</ns1:aanleverkenmerk>
     <ns1:identiteitBelanghebbende>
      <ns1:nummer/>
     <ns1:type/>
    </ns1:identiteitBelanghebbende>
   <ns1:rolBelanghebbende>Intermediair</ns1:rolBelanghebbende>
    <ns1:berichtInhoud>
     <ns1:mimeType/>
    <ns1:bestandsnaam/>
   <ns1:inhoud/>
  </ns1:berichtInhoud>
 <ns1:autorisatieAdres>https://secure.inepd.nl/inloon</ns1:autorisatieAdres>
  </ns1:aanleverRequest>
 </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out why, This might be a bit strange to answer my own question but maybe it might help someone in the future; It turned out that __getLastRequest() is not the actual last request in this case. So overriding __doRequest is an option but do not use __getLastRequest in such case!

Answer (score 0):

As you discovered, `__getLastRequest()` returns the request that is sent to `__do_Request()`    not the request that goes out over the wire...

you have two options:

a) override __getLastRequest (in addition to __doRequest)

b) add a few lines to your __doRequest method to updated SoapClient's private `__last_request` property

```
    if (PHP_VERSION_ID >= 80100) {
        $lastRequestRef = new \ReflectionProperty('SoapClient', '__last_request');
        $lastRequestRef->setAccessible(true);
        $lastRequestRef->setValue($this, $modifiedRequest);
    } else {
        $this->__last_request = $modifiedRequest;
    }
```