# SOAP attributes on body

Tags: php, soap

I have to consume webservice. My problem is that there are attributes like xmlns:wsu on the body tag. How can I pass this values to the body?

The body should looks like

```
<soap:Body xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="id-1">
<!-- some stuff -->
</soap:Body>
```

My PHP function

```
$soapClient = new SoapClient(
    'some.wsdl',
    array(
        'location' => 'url'
    )
);

$soapClient->myFunction($request);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to stack**overflow** Graccem,

the attributes you mentioned are namespaces. These are added automatically by the soap client to your xml when sending the request. Another possoble solution could be using the __doRequest() method of the soap client. In this case you have to extend the soap client class.

```
declare(strict_types=1);
namespace Application\Soap;

class MySoapClient extends SoapClient
{
    public function __doRequest(string $request, string $location, string $action, int $version, int $one_way = 0): string
    {
        $doc = new DOMDocument();
        $doc->loadXML($request);

        $elements = $doc->getElementsByNameNS('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/', 'Body');
        if ($elements->length()) {
            $body = $elements->item(0);
            $body->setAttributeNS('http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd', 'wsu:Id', 'id-1');
        }

        $request = $doc->saveXML();
        $this->__last_request = $request;

        return parent::__doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way);
    }
}
```

The `SoapClient::__doRequest()` method takes the fully formed xml request as first parameter. This method is the last chance manipulating the xml before sending it.

How to use it ...

```
try {
    $wsdl = 'some.wsdl';
    $options = [
        'exceptions' => true,
        'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1,
        'trace' => true,
    ];

    $data = []; // some data construct

    $client = new MySoapClient($wsdl, $options);
    $response = $client->doSomeAction($data);
} catch (SoapFault $fault) {
    $lastRequest = $lastResponse = '';
    if ($client instanceof SoapClient) {
        $lastRequest = $client->__getLastRequest();
        $lastResponse = $client->__getLastResponse();
    }
    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($fault, $lastRequest, $lastResponse);
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

We 're using the `trace` option here to see, what we 've sent and what we get as response in a fault case. Die `wsu:Id` attribute should now be in your xml request.

Comment: Hello Marcel, thanks for help. I modified  $request in __doRequest, however __getLastRequest shows the old code. I found one thread here  with the same issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42856124/php-soapclient-override-dorequest-does-not-change-xml-after-str-replace

Comment: Ah yeah. This is a known problem. The last request is saved before the execution of the `__doRequest()` method of the soap client. I 've edited my answer. The last request is stored in the internal property `__last_request`. If you output the last request now with `$client->__getLastRequest();` you should get the manipulated last request.